# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sentry"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, sentry

I have this error in my symfony 4 project :

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sentry" (in C:\SourceGit\Sentry\taxeapprentissage\config/packages/sentry.yaml). Looked for namespace "sentry", found "framework", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "maker", "twig", "monolog", "web_profiler", "security", "doctrine_fixtures", "sensio_framework_extra", "swiftmailer", "it_input_mask", "captcha" in C:\SourceGit\Sentry\taxeapprentissage\config/packages/sentry.yaml (which is loaded in resource "C:\SourceGit\Sentry\taxeapprentissage\config/packages/sentry.yaml").

Can you help me ?

I want to install sentry in my symfony 4 project. I have 2 environments, dev and prod.

Comment: have you followed the [guide](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/symfony/) to install sentry in symfony, specifically the part you have to do, if you're *not* using symfony/flex? ... do that one anyway! It's very likely, either that, or you haven't included the sentry-bundle but something else.

Answer (score 2):

It appears their install script has a bug. I had the exact same issue. They speak of a config in `packages/sentry.yaml`, but it exists in `packages/PROD/sentry.yaml`. When moving it up a directory, it gives the error from the start post.

After a composer install, the bundles.php says:

```
Sentry\SentryBundle\SentryBundle::class => ['prod' => true],
```

Which means it doesnt load unless env=PROD. Their documentation however uses `['all' => true]`.